# How do I use jQuery for flow control from an if statement?

Tags: jquery, control-flow

example:

```
if(login()) {

// jQuery to change CSS attribute from hidden to visible

}
```

I want to present the user with a input form if logged in, otherwise they don't see the form.

Thanks,

Comment: The question in the title and summary don't seem to make much sense together.

Comment: `$('loginformselector').show()`

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
if(login()) {

        $('#inputthing').show();

    } else {

        $('#inputthing').hide();
    }
```